# how to make conditional on file presence on activity bar views?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hello I am trying to make new extension that has a view that does not show till an html file exists. Otherwise, show a welcome view. I have the following snippet:

```
    "contributes": {
        "viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
              {
                "id": "mainview",
                "title": "View",
                "icon": "resources/icon.png"
              }
            ]
          },
 "viewsWelcome": [
            {
              "view": "view-welcome",
              "contents": "To learn more about the best workflow read the docs",
              "when": "!workspaceContains:**/*.html"
            }
          ],
"views": {
            "myextensionView": [
               {
                "id": "html-dir",
                "name": "Models",
                "when": "workspaceContains:*.html"
            },
             {
                "id": "view-welcome",
                "name": "Project Starter"
              }

}

``

However, "workspaceContains:*html" is always false and I am always getting the welcome view.

Any guidance on that?
```

Comment: in  the extension create a context variable that signals the state you want and depend the view on that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to the right direction using a [When Clause Context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts), but `workspaceContains` is not a **when clause**, it is an [Activation Event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#workspaceContains).

If you look closer at [When Clause Context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts), you won't see any when clause  similar to what you need, so you have to [Add a custom when clause context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#add-a-custom-when-clause-context) yourself.

You should create something like this in your `package.json`:

```json
    "viewsWelcome": [
        {
            "view": "view-welcome",
            "contents": "To learn more about the best workflow read the docs",
            "when": "!myExtension.myWorkspaceContainsSomeHtmlFile"
        }
   ],
```

And, in your extension source, you are responsible for detecting `Html` files in the workspace, and call `setContext` to activate/deactivate the when clause:

```js
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExtension.myWorkspaceContainsSomeHtmlFile', hasHtmlFilesInsideTheWorkspace());
```

Be aware that the same `setContext` command can/should be called as many times as necessary. For instance, you could create a `FileWatcher` on your workspace to *detect* creation/deletion of `.html` files to *update* the visibility of your Side Bar. It depends entirely of your needs

Hope this helps